# Sort a 2D array columns by first row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D array like bellow:

```js
[['c', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
 ['1', '5', '7', '8'],
 ['3', '7', '4', '9']];
```

What could be the best way to sort the columns by first row values:

```js
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['8', '7', '1', '5'],
 ['9', '4', '3', '7']];
```

The values on first row are expected to be unique.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-matrix-row-wise-column-wise/

Comment: @cybercoder The URL you gave is not exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: @user5507535 does my answer below get the job done?

Comment: Hi @bel3atar your code seemed to work, I did found what seems a simpler solution though.

Comment: @user5507535 can you share?

Comment: @bel3atar It's among the answers already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to transpose the matrix, then sort it and transpose back:

```js
let arr =
[['c', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
 ['1', '5', '7', '8'],
 ['3', '7', '4', '9']];

arr = arr[0].map((_, colIndex) => arr.map(row => row[colIndex]));

arr.sort((a,b) => a[0] > b[0]);

arr = arr[0].map((_, colIndex) => arr.map(row => row[colIndex]));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Sort the first column array with its index.

Then, whole array with its index.

```
const res = [
  ["c", "d", "b", "a"],
  ["1", "5", "7", "8"],
  ["3", "7", "4", "9"],
];
const sort2dArrayColumsByFirstRow = (array) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) return [];
  const sortedFirstRow = array[0]
    .map((item, i) => ({ v: item, i: i }))
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return a.v < b.v ? -1 : 1;
    });
  return array.map((row) => row.map((_, i) => row[sortedFirstRow[i].i]));
};

console.log(sort2dArrayColumsByFirstRow(res));
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const input = [
  ['c', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
  ['1', '5', '7', '8'],
  ['3', '7', '4', '9']
];

const temp = input[0].map(
  (letter, index) => [letter, input[1][index], input[2][index]]
)

temp.sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))

const result = temp.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.forEach((x, i) => acc[i].push(x));
  return acc;
}, [[],[],[]]) ;

console.log(result)
```

Or you can remember the steps you followed to sort the first array and apply them to the rest.

```js
const arrayLoop = arr => {
  let i = 0;
  return () => arr[i++ % arr.length]
}

const sortAndRememberSteps = arr => {
  const steps = [];
  arr.sort((a, b) => { const step = a.localeCompare(b); steps.push(step); return step });
  return steps;
}

const input = [
  ['c', 'd', 'b', 'a'],
  ['1', '5', '7', '8'],
  ['3', '7', '4', '9']
];

const [arrayToSort, ...rest] = input

const steps = sortAndRememberSteps(arrayToSort);

rest.forEach(arr => arr.sort(arrayLoop(steps)))

console.log(input)
```